# a link in my codeigniter website only works on reload

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, frameworks

I am developing a website on Codeigniter Framework i am facing an issue while making forgot password feature.

When i submit my email address it sends an email to that address and that email has a link that has a token in it. eg:
http://www.myegsite.com/user/forgotyourpassword/2991c14654e1ed41aab1565dcf815b0f

On click that link, if that token is not expired then, website asks for your new password and confirm password.

The issue is : When i provide new password and confirm password and click submit button it gives me following error:

> An Error Was Encountered
>   The action you have requested is not allowed.

After reloading that same link, the page i get works absolutely fine, it updates my password again.

What could be the reason that link doesn't work first time?

**Controller:**

```
public function forgotyourpassword($token)
{
    if($this->session->userdata('user_data') != NULL)
    {
         redirect(base_url() . 'User');
    }else
    {
     //check if token exist in table or not , if not exist return false;
        $this->load->model("data_access/extradataaccess","ExtraDataAccess");
        $dbToken =$this->ExtraDataAccess->getToken($token);
        if($dbToken == FALSE)
            {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("invalid_token",'This token is invalid!');
            redirect(base_url() . 'welcome/forgotPassword');
        }
        else
        {
         //check if current date is smaller than expiry data , it means token is still valid return true;   
        if($this->ExtraDataAccess->GetTokenInfo($token) == FALSE)
        {
            //set flash data session for token expired

            redirect(base_url() . 'welcome/forgotPassword');

            //if token is expired return false
        } //if ($currDate <= $expiryDate)
        else
        {       
            // load form libraries
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('confpassword', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[20]|matches[password]');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            { 
                $this->data['page_name'] = "Renew Password";
                $this->data['form_url'] = base_url()."user/forgotyourpassword/";
                $this->data['token'] = "$token";
                $this->load->view("welcome/renewpassword_view",$this->data);

            }
            else
            {   
                $tokenEmail = $this->ExtraDataAccess->GetTokenInfo($token)['email'];
                $hashPassword = md5($this->input->post('password'));

                //updating password into the database
                $updateData = array (

                    'password' => $hashPassword
                ); 
                $this->db->where('email',$tokenEmail);
                $this->db->update('users',$updateData);

            }  
           }//else
        }
    }//if($this->session->userdata('user_data') != NULL)
}//Forgotyourpassword()
```

**View:**

```
<?php echo form_open("$form_url"."$token"); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputpass">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputpass" value="" php echo placeholder="new password"/>
</div>
<?php if(form_error('password')!=NULL){
    echo "<div id='fielderror'>";
    echo form_error('password'); 
    echo "</div>";
}?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputpassconf">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="confpassword" class="form-control" id="inputpassconf" value="" placeholder="confirm password"/>
</div>
<?php if(form_error('confpassword')!=NULL){
    echo "<div id='fielderror'>";
    echo form_error('confpassword'); 
    echo "</div>";
}?>

<h5><input type="submit" value="Reset Password" class="btn btn-info active"/></h5>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: We need the controller function and probably the form in the view

Comment: ok let me add the code for controller and view.

Comment: <?php echo form_open("$form_url"."$token"); ?>
this line is first line in the view code. i don't know why site is not displaying this line.

Comment: remove `base_url() . ` in your redirect()

Comment: Thanks sir. but this base_url() has the url of my site and i can access that basic url everywhere in my web app. if i remove this so what should i use in replace? should i hardcode the url everywhere in the page?

Comment: When you use redirect("controller/function"); codeigniter will rebuild a full url eg example.com/index.php/controller/function. Moreover, base_url() does't have index.php in it

Comment: actually i am new to codeigniter thats why do not understand many of its errors. thanks for your help.
and yeah but i am already using .htaccess file way to remove index.php from my link... should i still remove base_url() ???

Comment: You can tru, but your issue is somewhere else? Do you use CSRF tokens ? Please try to set $config['cookie_secure'] in config file to FALSE

Comment: ok i will try this but i dont know CSRF. i copied this function that generates a token.


`private function generateToken(){
       // Time based PHP Unique ID
   $uid = uniqid(NULL, TRUE);
   // Random SHA1 hash
   $rawid = strtoupper(sha1(uniqid(rand(), true)));
   // Produce the results
   $result = substr($uid, 6, 8);
   $result .= substr($uid, 0, 4);
   $result .= substr(sha1(substr($uid, 3, 3)), 0, 4);
   $result .= substr(sha1(substr(time(), 3, 4)), 0, 4);
   $result .= strtolower(substr($rawid, 10, 12));
   // Return the result
   return $result;
   }`

Comment: $config['cookie_secure'] is already set to FALSE in config file.

Comment: In your config file, is $config['csrf_protection'] set to false ?

Comment: nope its 
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;

Comment: Can this issue occur because of .htaccess file. there are plenty of different codes out there for .htaccess file. The one i am using might be wrong. if yes which one should i use then?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with your .htaccess, but yes, it can be an issue.

Comment: if i change $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE to FALSE. it works but i need csrf protection. i cannot keep it FALSE.

Comment: Then you have to check the doc about CSRF tokens. You should handle your token with the built-in methods. Unfortunately I don't have time to help you further than that today.

Comment: @AdrienXL thanks till yet bro. you have been very helpful. I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: I got a good news. One of my friends have resolved the issue.

Comment: In my config file $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:9999/myegsite.com/'; 
and the link i was sending through email was like: http://www.myegsite.com/user/forgotyourpassword/2991c14654e1ed41aab1565dcf815b0f. Hence the problem is link contains www in it whereas base_url doesnt, thats why it was showing that error.